# Can cy.origin wait longer for a redirect?

Tags: cypress, cypress-origin

I have some code that visits my page, which then redirects for authentication.  The issue is the page takes too long to do the redirect, so cy.origin times out before the domain it is targeting is loaded.  Is there a way (other than an evil hard coded wait) to get cy.origin to wait longer for the domain it's targeting?

I tried cy.url().should('match', /^authurl.com/) before the cy.origin call, but of course that won't work because cy.url() is cross domain by the time authurl.com is loaded (cy.url() seems to return blank at that time).  I tried putting cy.url().should('match', /^authurl.com/) inside the origin call, but I think that's redundant, as it won't execute until the authurl.com domain is loaded.

Any suggestions?

```
  cy.visit(Cypress.config().baseUrl)
  
  cy.origin( 'authurl.com', { args: { username, password } }, 
   ({ username, password }) => {   
      // Enter username and submit.
      cy.get('input[type="email"]').type(username, { log: false })
      cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click()

      // Enter password and submit.
      cy.get('input[type="password"]').type(password, { log: false })
      cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution similar to the first option suggested by @aladin-spaz, just using url() instead of location(), and located at the top of the origin instead of the bottom.

```
 cy.visit(Cypress.config().baseUrl)
  
  // Login to your AAD tenant.
  cy.origin( 'authurl.com', { args: { username, password } }, 
   ({ username, password }) => {
      cy.url().should('match', /^https:\/\/authurl\.com/, { timeout: 90000 })

      // Enter username and submit.
      cy.get('input[type="email"]').type(username, { log: false })
      cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click()

      // Enter password and submit.
      cy.get('input[type="password"]').type(password, { log: false })
      cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click()
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you might make an assertion on the location, ref [cy.location - options](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/location#Arguments)

```js
cy.origin( 'authurl.com', { args: { username, password } }, 
   ({ username, password }) => {   
      // Enter username and submit.
      cy.get('input[type="email"]').type(username, { log: false })
      cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click()

      // Enter password and submit.
      cy.get('input[type="password"]').type(password, { log: false })
      cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click()

     
      cy.location({timeout:10_000})
        .should((loc) => {
          expect(loc.href).to.eq(Cypress.config().baseUrl)
        })
    }
```

Or if it's the auth page that's slow, just add timeout to the email query

```js
cy.origin( 'authurl.com', { args: { username, password } }, 
   ({ username, password }) => {   

      // Try with redirecting cy.visit() inside the origin
      cy.visit(Cypress.config().baseUrl)

      // Add timeout here to wait for auth page to load
      cy.get('input[type="email"]', {timeout:10_000})
        .type(username, { log: false })

      cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click()

      // Enter password and submit.
      cy.get('input[type="password"]').type(password, { log: false })
      cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click()
    }
```

Comment: It's authurl.com that takes a long time to load...doesn't the cy.origin call block until that domain is loaded?  If that is the case, the code you've added inside the origin callback will not run until the authurl.com domain is loaded...

Comment: Not sure that's the case, I haven't seen it mentioned in the docs. Can you post the full error, there may be some clues there.

Comment: Oh, I have another tweak - move the visit inside the origin. Seems to break the rules, but it has worked before.

Comment: as you requested, here is the error:

Timed out retrying after 30000ms: The command was expected to run against origin `https://authurl.com` but the application is at origin `https://appurl.com`.

This commonly happens when you have either not navigated to the expected origin or have navigated away unexpectedly.

Using `cy.origin()` to wrap the commands run on `https://appurl.com` will likely fix this issue.